# Unable to parse Json properly with SwiftyJson

Tags: json, swift, rest, alamofire, swifty-json

I have the folllowing Json response:

```
 `       [Body]:
    {"id":"cmpl-6Z45N6vfd2312vdfqyYPb8aDRVe9Nft7vfnpoEsL","object":"text_completion","created":16738vfv15205,"model":"text-davinci-003","choices":[{"text":"\n1. Full Stack Developer\n2. Project Engineering Intern\n3. AI Programmer\n4. Systems Trade Studies Engineer\n5. BLE Technology Developer\n6. macOS Menu Bar App Developer\n7. Mobile App Developer\n8. Research Engineer\n9. Writing and Design Lab Researcher","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":"stop"}],"usage":{"prompt_tokens":726,"completion_tokens":60,"total_tokens":786}}`
```

And I'm using SwiftyJson and Alamofire to parse the Json using the following code:

```
`     AF.request(...).responseJSON { response in
                
                print("response: \(response)")
                
                
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    if let JSON = response.value as! [[String : Any]]?{
                               print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                        let dic = JSON[0] as [String:AnyObject]?
                               print("TitularEmail : ",dic?["choices"])
                           }
                       break

                   case .failure(_):
                       print("There is an error")
                       break
               }
        }`
```

But it keeps breaking and I keep getting the error 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT' at  'if let JSON = response.value as! [[String : Any]]?{'

Does anyone know what could've gone wrong? I've read through quite some threads but I can't seem to figure this out. Any info shall be appreciated.

Comment: there is definitely something wrong with "created":16738vfv15205

Comment: Shoot yeah lol but that can't cause the error. I cleared the console but the lemme reproduce the error and update the response

Comment: `SwiftyJSON` is a deserving library, but since Swift 4 (5 years ago) it's obsolete in favor of `Codable` which even Alamofire supports today.

Comment: FYI - using `as!` in an `if let` is a bit of an oxymoron. You want `if let JSON = response.value as? [[String : Any]] {`. But clearly your response value isn't an array of dictionary which is why the forced cast is crashing.

Comment: Yeah caodable was the best option out there. I got it working after being inspired from @Ben's answer from below.

Comment: Your original code would likely work if you changed the cast from `[[String : Any]]` to `[String : Any]` (from array of dictionary to just dictionary). But Codable is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) would be a much better alternative. At the risk of slightly wandering from the original SwiftyJSON question, I highly recommend using `Decodable` to parse JSON (see also [Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) for writing and [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) for the combination of both). Here's an example of a very basic use of `Decodable`. Supposed you want to parse the following:

```
{
"name": "New York City",
"mayor": "Eric Adams",
"population": 8468000
}
```

You can parse it super easily with `Decodable`:

```
struct City: Decodable {
    let name:String
    let mayor:String
    let population:Int
}
```

You can create an instance of `City` in this example by taking the JSON– assume it is stored in a variable called `jsonData`– and simply doing the following:

```
let NYC = try JSONDecoder().decode(City.self, from: jsonData)
```

You should highly consider this route because it can get a lot done with very little work.

You can also use [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) if you don't want to use the aforementioned ways of parsing it. [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-parse-json-using-jsonserialization) is a simple tutorial on how to do that.

In your case, you can implement `Decodable` to solve your problem like this:

```
var json = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "PATH TO FILE WITH EXAMPLE JSON TEXT"))


struct FirstStruct:Decodable {
    let id:String
    let object:String
    let created:String //I'm calling this a string because, despite the lack of quotes, it has letters in it and cannot be an Int. You could also do something like Int? so it can fail safely if there are letters. I am adding quotes to the example text make it work.
    let model:String
    let choices:[SecondStruct]
    let usage:ThirdStruct
    
}

struct SecondStruct:Decodable {
    let text:String
    let index:Int
    let logprobs:String? //idk what type this is supposed to be from the text given
    let finish_reason:String
}

struct ThirdStruct:Decodable {
    let prompt_tokens:Int
    let completion_tokens:Int
    let total_tokens:Int
}

var test = try! JSONDecoder().decode(FirstStruct.self, from: json)

print(test.id) 
print(test.usage.total_tokens) //these two examples show it clearly works here
```

Obviously, have a bit more care with error handling, `try!` was just easier for the example.

Comment: Hey Ben, so after several attempts and scouring the internet and finally using quicktype to get my struct going, I tried this but I"m getting the error "No exact matches in call to initializer  when I call Data(Json)". Any clue what could've gone wrong? :/

Comment: @Mansidak In this case, `Data(contents of:)` requires a URL. Usually, you could use a URL to the API endpoint you want, for example. In my case above, I used a URL of a file path. I assume you are attempting to do it with a string? If your `Json` is a string, then it should work if you instead do `Json.data(using: .utf8)`. It should return a value of type Data? that can be later used as the second parameter in JSONDecoder().decode().

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had the same feeling and I tried Json.data(using: .utf8) but I had two errors after that: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'utf8', and Value of type '[[String : Any]]' has no member 'data'. Is it because I'm unwrapping it as Dict? I'm kinda confused what could've gone wrong with this :/